# ScriptHost error occured despite catching an exception

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a simple function that takes a message from a queue and saves it to a storage table. I expect that in some cases a table entity with the same data can already exist. Because of that, I added an exception handling to skip this type of situation and mark the queue message as processed. Despite the fact that exception is handled now, the scripthost informs me about an error and the message is still in the queue.

I suppose it is caused by the fact that I'm using table binding that is on edge between host and my code. Am I right? Should I use a table client within my code instead of binding? Is there a different approach?

Sample code to generate this situation:

```
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "Conn")]string msg, [Table("mytable", Connection = "Conn")] IAsyncCollector<DataEntity> dataEntity, TraceWriter log)
    {
        try
        {
            await dataEntity.AddAsync(new DataEntity()
            {
                PartitionKey = "1",
                RowKey = "1",
                Data = msg
            });
            await dataEntity.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch (StorageException e)
        {
           // when it is an exception that informs "entity already exists" skip it
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When a **queue trigger** function fails, **Azure Functions retries** the function up to five times for a given queue message, including the first try.

If all five attempts fail, the functions runtime adds a message to a queue named `<originalqueuename>-poison`.

You can write a function to process messages from the [poison queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---poison-messages) by logging them or sending a notification that manual attention is needed.

The [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---hostjson-properties) file contains settings that control queue trigger behavior:

```
{
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": 2000,
      "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 16,
      "maxDequeueCount": 1,
      "newBatchThreshold": 8
    }
}
```

**Note**: **maxDequeueCount default is 5**. The number of times to try processing a message before moving it to the poison queue. For your need, you could set the `"maxDequeueCount":1`.

Also these settings are host wide and apply to all functions. You can't control these per function currently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it won't resolve my issue. I know how queue trigger behaves (about its retry-policy, poison queue etc.) and I think it isn't the point. The problem is that I'm catching an exception and despite that I'm getting scripthost error.